# What is FederatedPassiveSignIn replacement in WIF 4.5

Tags: .net-4.5

As from MS, FederatedPassiveSignIn is no longer supported in WIF 4.5, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157091.aspx.  I want to know how to replace that control on asp.net page for an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've built a replacement and published to a community. It now supports a basic button style and an auto sign in, I am open to bug submits and feature requests.

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2013/06/federatedpassivesignin-for-wif-and.html